# Accounting for ListView sort while ignoring leading "The" in Android

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` that is populated by three (3) `ArrayList`'s:

`items`, `ratings` and `comments`

However, I need to sort items by ignoring the leading 'the'.  I already have accomplished this by rearranging the `items` `ArrayList` using a `Collections.sort` (see code below), but this is the issue:  the comments and ratings are not rearranged so it comes out of order in the `ListView`.

For example, if the list was:

1. Cars 3 4
2. People 5 3
3. The Animals 7 4

After `items` sort I am getting:

1. The Animals 3 4
2. Cars 5 3
3. People 7 4

So the `items` are lining up as I'd like but the associated `comments` and `ratings`  aren't sorted.  I am not sure how to make that happen and where to place it.  I think in the ArrayAdapter?

Here is the code I do to change the `items` list:

```
        Comparator<String> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                a = a.replaceAll("(?i)^the\\s+", "");
                b = b.replaceAll("(?i)^the\\s+", "");
                return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(items, ignoreLeadingThe);
```

Here is the questions?  Where and how can I sort the ratings and comments lists based on the position of the item list?

**Edit:**

this is my getView code in my `ArrayAdapter`:

```
    ItemObject io = getItem(position);
    String name = io.name;
    String total = io.total;
    String rating = io.ratings;
    String comment = io.comments;

    holder.t1.setText(name);
    holder.t2.setText(total);
    holder.t3.setText(comment);
    holder.t4.setText(rating);
```

Note: There is a 4th `ArrayList` called `total` I did not mention in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at creating a class to wrap your items in the ArrayList, something like this:

```
class MyItem {
    String item;
    int ratings;
    int comments;
}
```

Then have an ArrayList of these objects instead:

```
List<MyItem> myList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
```

Then in your comparator, just do it like you're doing, but testing against `MyItem.item` instead of just `a` and `b`. Something like this:

```
Comparator<MyItem> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<MyItem>() {
    public int compare(MyItem a, MyItem b) {
        a.item = a.item.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        b.item = b.item.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        return a.item.compareToIgnoreCase(b.item);
    }
};

Collections.sort(myList, ignoreLeadingThe);
```

Comment: That's brilliant!  I already have a class like that I am using.  I have updated my question to show you how I output from the class/object in the getView method.  Is this where I would use your code above? Or do I do this in the main ListActivity before I call the adapter?

Comment: Yup! You can just use your `ItemObject` class instead of the `MyItem` class that I used as an example.

Comment: Ok, one more quick question on implementation: I am not sure what to put in the `Collections.sort`.  It has to be a List, right? Are we really sorting "items"? Aren't we sorting the ItemObject now?

Comment: You're sorting a `List` of `ItemObject`s. `items` should be an `ArrayList<ItemObject>`. I just copied `items` from your description, but from my example, it should've been `myList`. I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought.  That is working in my code with no errors..  Though nothing is being sort yet (based on trimming the "the"'s).  I am actually attempting this sort before my Adapter is set rather than in my Adapter.  (Hope that's right?) I'll mark you correct cause I think you got me on the right path!

Comment: That should be right -- sort before setting the adapter, definitely. As far as your comparator and comparing ignoring "the", I actually didn't even look at how you implemented it -- I just assumed that it was working properly when I copy-pasted. :)

Comment: Nah, I figured it out.  I actually wasn't using an ArrayList for the object, I was using an Array like this:  `ItemObject[] io = new ItemObject[items.size()];`  So I had to do this instead of aCollections: `Arrays.sort(io, ignoreLeadingThe);`  - Now it's working! Thanks again!